# PostgreSQL table locking conflicts

Tags: postgresql

I'm reading this document on [Explicit Locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/explicit-locking.html) and when they are automatically used by PostgreSQL.

What happens when one lock conflicts with another? Does the second transaction just wait until the first finishes? Does it abort?

So say some transaction opens up an ACCESS SHARE lock on table called `apples`. Then say another transaction tries to add a column issuing an `ALTER TABLE` query which is an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock. What happens to the second query? Does it hang? Abort?

Comment: postgresql has a good help on concurrency control. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/mvcc.html

Answer (score 0):

The second query `ALTER TABLE` waits for the first transaction to complete. You can see that in `pg_locks`.

```
Select * from pg_locks;
```

**To simulate this scenario:-**

1) Open three separate SQL Editors in pgAdmin

2) SQL Editor 1: Execute the below statements

```
BEGIN;
   Select * FROM table_name;
```

3) SQL Editor 2: Check the locks using `pg_locks`. There should be `AccessShareLock`

4) SQL Editor 3:

```
BEGIN;
  alter table table_name ADD COLUMN new_column varchar(30);
```

The window should show `Query is running`.

5) SQL Editor 2: Check the locks using `pg_locks`. There should be `AccessExclusiveLock`

6) SQL Editor 1: Execute `END;` (i.e. Ending the select transaction)

7) SQL Editor 3: Query (i.e. alter table) should be executed successfully

8) SQL Editor 2: Check the locks using `pg_locks`. There shouldn't be any 'AccessShare' lock

9) SQL Editor 3: Execute `END;` (i.e. Ending the alter table transaction)

10) SQL Editor 2: Check the locks using `pg_locks`. There shouldn't be any 'AccessExclusive' lock.